# Can't login on MacBook Air running OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.2

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, login

I can't login to my Mac. It boots correctly, but after I put my *correct* password, it shows a grey screen and goes back to login screen.

Comment: Any chance it could a different keyboard layout active than the one you normally use when logging in.

Comment: Can you login as Guest?

Comment: Really weird it accepts your password, and then tries to log you in, which fails. My initial gut feeling was that somehow your user folder is not where your extended Users & Groups settings says it is. Could this be?

Comment: To verify your boot, type wrong password.

Answer (score 1):

No, it can't really be said to be booting correctly. Do you have a startup disk or clone from which you can run Disk Utility, which is the only way to fully repair a disk? Not that such can necessarily fix every problem, but a hard disk cannot fully repair itself.

Does a Safe Boot work? Holding down Command-Shift at startup. The System fixes various little things in the process, then you Restart again after logging in.

How about Verbose Mode? Hold down Command-S. That will take you to a command-line prompt, and there are some repair tricks that can be performed from there.

Let us know!

Comment: Already tried them all, safe boot, system fix in verbose mode, nothing work, and i dont have a startup disk to fix it...

Comment: So what is the last thing you saw in the command line before the loop.